# Using reactive method in a template event

Tags: forms, asynchronous, meteor

I've been using reactive methods to help return my data from some asynchronous meteor methods. This does not seem to work with forms and I was wondering what the work around it? I receive:

> > Don't use ReactiveMethod.call outside of a Tracker computation.

with the following files:
submit.js

```
Template.makeTransaction.events({
  'submit form': function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // construct the contact object that will be passed to the method
    var add = event.target.receiver.value;
    var amount = Number(event.target.amount.value);
    var comm = event.target.comment.value
    var request = {
      address: add,
      qty: amount,
      comment: comm,
      asset:'pounds'
    };
    return ReactiveMethod.call('sendAsset', request, function(err, result){ 
    });
  }
});
```

meteormethods.js

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendAsset: function(request){
    var sync=Meteor.wrapAsync(user.sendAssetToAddress, user);
    var data = sync({request});
    return data;
  },
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers (your `'submit form': function(event) {...}`) are not reactive. Template helpers are, but they are not the same thing.

What you are doing is a bit strange, since the event handler runs only once, when the event triggers. So in that handler, you should use the "normal" async method of receiving the result of your Meteor.call:

```
Meteor.call( 'sendAsset', request, function(err, result) { 
    if( err ) { /* Handle error */ return; }
    // Here you use the result.
});
```

Returning a value from an event handler, as you are doing now, is a bit pointless. There is nothing receiving this value.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - is there a better approach to this that is less bizarre? could you describe a bit more about the normal async method so I could look it up - unfortunately I'm not proficient enough at meteor to know what is normal yet :)

Comment: Do I need to adjust the Meteor.wrapAsync code? As is I am getting: Exception while invoking method 'sendAsset' undefined. Thank you

Comment: This depends on user.sendAssetToAddress(). wrapAsync is for NPM package methods that want a function(error, result) callback. See https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#wrap-async. If it is a normal method you should not use wrapAsync

Comment: You can console.log(err) to get more info on why the server method is crashing.